# How can I get the Scala.js 1.3.0 tutorial to run?

Tags: scala.js

I thought I would try out Scala.js 1.3.0, but I cannot get the tutorial at [scalajs-tutorial](https://github.com/scala-js/scalajs-tutorial) to run following the instructions at [Basic Turorial](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/tutorial/basic/) What I get is

```
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last Compile / scalaJSIR for the full output
[error] (Compile / scalaJSIR) java.nio.file.FileSystemLoopException: G:\My Drive\Git\scalajs-tutorial\target\scala-2.13\classes\tutorial
[error] Total time: 15 s, completed Oct. 16, 2020, 9:24:08 a.m.
sbt:Scala.js Tutorial>
sbt:Scala.js Tutorial> last Compile / scalaJSIR
[error] java.nio.file.FileSystemLoopException: G:\My Drive\Git\scalajs-tutorial\target\scala-2.13\classes\tutorial
[error]         at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:294)
[error]         at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.next(FileTreeWalker.java:373)
[error]         at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2840)
[error]         at org.scalajs.linker.PathIRContainer$.org$scalajs$linker$PathIRContainer$$walkIR(PathIRContainer.scala:95)
[error]         at org.scalajs.linker.PathIRContainer$.$anonfun$fromClasspath$4(PathIRContainer.scala:37)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$foreach$1(TraversableLike.scala:877)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:876)
[error]         at org.scalajs.linker.PathIRContainer$.$anonfun$fromClasspath$2(PathIRContainer.scala:33)
[error]         at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$DefaultThreadFactory$$anon$1$$anon$2.block(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:75)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3127)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$DefaultThreadFactory$$anon$1.blockOn(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:87)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.package$.blocking(package.scala:146)
[error]         at org.scalajs.linker.PathIRContainer$.$anonfun$fromClasspath$1(PathIRContainer.scala:33)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
[error]         at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
[error]         at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1429)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1016)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1665)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1598)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
[error] (Compile / scalaJSIR) java.nio.file.FileSystemLoopException: G:\My Drive\Git\scalajs-tutorial\target\scala-2.13\classes\tutorial
```

I don't know why there would be a loop in the file system, since I used `git clone` to get the repo.

Answer (score 1):

So, the reason there may be a loop in the file system is that I was running the repo in a directory on Google Drive File Stream. This does not seem to be a safe place to build SBT projects...

Moving the repo to the C: drive on my local system solved that problem, but the project still fails to build/run... more to come on a different post...